# Streaming files from a react frontend to a node js backend for processing

Tags: reactjs, express, csv

Does anyone here have experience streaming files from a react frontend (doesn't need to be react) to an express backend? How did you do it?

Instead of loading in a huge string representation of the user's CSV file and sending that in the request body, I want to be able to continuously stream chunks of the file (possibly millions of rows), and process that data on the api side, chunk by chunk.

After processing/transforming the CSV, I'd like to stream it back to the frontend; again, chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Node has a function for these, take a look on the fs.createReadStream() function.

Comment: I am aware of these functions, however they don't solve the problem I'm facing with streaming data from the frontend to the backend.